# BIND, in-view and dynamic updates

Tags: bind

I have one zone in two views in BIND 9.10, sharing the same information via "in-view":

Zone included in view A:

```
zone "foo.tld" in {
    type master;
    allow-update {
        key "some.key.id";
    };
    file "pri/pri.foo.tld";
};
```

Zone included in view B:

```
zone "foo.tld" in {
    in-view A;
};
```

The problem: Dynamic updates via the key does work if the requester is reaching view A (e.g. from internal network), but not if the request is made within view B (e.g. from external).

I tried an "allow-update-forwarding" in zone, this is not allowed. Using it in the view definition, it does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related - https://serverfault.com/questions/592492/updates-to-a-bind-dynamic-zone-that-is-shared-between-views-delayed.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this guidance in a thread titled: [BIND-9.10.2-P4: Cannot use in-view to refer to RPZ zone definitions: "'$RPZ_ZONE' is not a master or slave zone"](http://bind-users-forum.2342410.n4.nabble.com/BIND-9-10-2-P4-Cannot-use-in-view-to-refer-to-RPZ-zone-definitions-quot-RPZ-ZONE-is-not-a-master-or--td1130.html) which had this suggestion/guidance:

> If you remove the `"allow-update { any; };"` named doesn't treat the 
>   file as writeable.  It's not file permissions.  It's whether named 
>   will potentially update the file itself or not.

I'd try removing that from the A view.

```
zone "foo.tld" in {
    type master;
#    allow-update {
#        key "some.key.id";
#    };
    file "pri/pri.foo.tld";
};
```

#### References

- [BIND-9.10.2-P4: Cannot use in-view to refer to RPZ zone definitions: "'$RPZ_ZONE' is not a master or slave zone"](http://bind-users-forum.2342410.n4.nabble.com/BIND-9-10-2-P4-Cannot-use-in-view-to-refer-to-RPZ-zone-definitions-quot-RPZ-ZONE-is-not-a-master-or--td1130.html)
- [Updates to a BIND dynamic zone that is shared between views delayed](https://serverfault.com/questions/592492/updates-to-a-bind-dynamic-zone-that-is-shared-between-views-delayed)